# Wireless router in checked or carry-on luggage

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, electronic-items, tsa

I bought a wireless router in the US which I plan to carry to Europe. My main issue is where to put it? I'm afarid of it being taken if it is in my backpack (since it does look like a thing to check out, being a box with antennas), and that it will be broken in the checked luggage. What to do?

Comment: I never saw a sinister looking wireless router. But I guess they come in many designs.

Comment: Sinister is probably an exaggeration, its a box with antennas and electronics in it, a regular Asus router. I'm just afraid that they don't get paranoid.

Comment: As an aside, European WiFi routers can use channels that US WiFi routers can't use - you might prefer to use a European-market one.  (European-market ones are illegal to use in the US unless you keep them on the US-permitted frequencies.  The WiFi band is a little larger in Europe than it is in the US.)

Comment: If it's still in the box and shrink wrapped it probably will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue with it in carry-on luggage. I have done this twice from the US to South America, so US security had no trouble with it which covers your case.

One can put it in checked-luggage but it risks getting stolen or damaged. Since routers do not cost so much, most insurance will cover it replacement and the airline does provide some coverage. Although if you got it in the US, the same may not be available in Europe, so I would recommend it in carry-on.

Comment: Just to summarize here, everything was ok. It was in my backpack, without the box (because the box was very large). I would take it out as any large electronic item, the staff looked it quickly and that's it. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 4):

There should be no problem putting it in your carry-on luggage, especially if it's in its original box, and even if it isn't.  Pretty much everybody has a wireless router these days, so the security staff will know what it is.